# Prove that the summation of product of co-factor of an element of a matrix with any other element is 0.

Tags: matrices, summation, determinant

Let A = ($a_{ij}$) be an $n×n$ matrix and $A_{ij}$ be the co-factor of $a_{ij}$.

Show that: 
              $\sum$ $a_{ik}$$A_{jk}$ = det($A$) if i=j, else 0

I couldn't think of any way to do this other than trying to open the co-factor, but I think that would be vigorous.

EDIT-  I've tried expanding, but there were a lot of terms, I got confused how I could accommodate them all. Also, as i is not equal to j, there are lots of cases. How can we generalize all that?

Comment: It looks to me as if the best way to do this is through induction. Have you tried that yet? Also: a thing I’ve found is useful in general is to never fear expanding and going through calculations too soon! If it’s too tedious to tackle, then discover that it is by trying rather than avoiding it altogether.

Comment: @user622002 I'm not sure how we can use induction here. Do we start that by going for a 2x2 matrix and then mxm matrix? And also, I've tried expanding, but there were a lot of terms, I got confused how I could accommodate them all. Also, as i is not equal to j, there are lots of cases. How can we generalize all that?

Comment: See answer below. One main question for you is how do you define the determinant and what properties do you know about it.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yes, I got it. It's a good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

- Replace the column $j$ of the matrix $A$ with column $i$.
- Then use cofactor expansion with regard to column $j$.
- If $j\neq i$, then obviously the result is equal to zero as we're expanding the determinant of a matrix having two columns equal.
- And if $j = i$, this is the classical formula of the determinant expansion according to column $j$ of the matrix $A$. A proof of this formula is provided at [Laplace expansion in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion). Another way to prove it is to prove that the determinant is an $n$-linear alternating form of the column vectors. See [properties of the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant).